# Is it possible to have a _layout.svelte for sub directories in ./routes with svelte-kit?

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to create a layout for a specific route...Doesn't seem to work:

```
./routes/guides/_layout.svelte
./routes/guides/page1.svelte
```

Does `_layout.svelte` only work at the root of `./routes`?

I'm using svelte-kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name would be `__layout.svelte` with 2 underscores, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Update from SvelteKit 1.0: `+layout.svelte`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).